# Elasticsearch aggregate to show data in two ways

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am working on a system that utilises Elasticsearch for reporting, and would like to fit some upcoming new data into the existing infrastructure. I can pre-process the data before indexing it in Elasticsearch, so consider the structure to be completely flexible.

The new data is going to consist of *many* small data points at a given time period, such as:

```
{
  "date": "2017-10-24T10:51:42Z",
  "points": [
    0.0018,
    0.13,
    0.0009,
    // …
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to aggregate this data in two separate ways, given a date range:

1. Total of all the values in the `points` array, aggregated and bucketed into hours, days, etc (date_histogram and sum work for this)
2. Total of *each* point, grouped by its index, for all documents in the date range

I can demonstrate the "correct" answer in JavaScript in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmy1hmap/1/), summarised here:

```
const FAKE_DATA = [
    { date: '2017-10-22T13:00:00Z', points: [0.00, 0.00051, 0.00009] },
    { date: '2017-10-22T13:01:00Z', points: [0.00, 0.00077, 0.00115] }
];

/**
 * X axis is time, Y axis is the total of all points in that row.
 */
function timeVsTotal() {
  return FAKE_DATA.map((row) => {
    return [Date.parse(row.date), row.points.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v)];
  });
}

/**
 * X is the index within points, Y is the total of points[0] for the 0th column, total of points[1] for the 1st, etc.
 */
function groupedTotal() {
  return FAKE_DATA
    .map((row) => row.points)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.map((n, i) => n + b[i]));
}
```

Is there a way to store this data in Elasticsearch so that a single document can represent a single "row" from `FAKE_DATA`, and I can use aggregations to get both answers?

Edit: it's been suggested somewhere else that I could pre-process the total of each item and store that in the doc to make the aggregation of time vs total easier on the server to calculate, but that still doesn't help me work out the cross-document totalling. At this stage, I think I might need to either write a groovy script that operates on the documents, or just get my middleware to fetch the documents and page through them, keeping a running total itself.